# How do I process a char with %d format specifier?

Tags: c++, c

I am taking values of a variable from  a file using `scanf` . It should continue reading from the file until it encounters a `%`. How do I compare `%`

```
scanf("%d",&a);

if (a=='$') terminate ; ??
```

It does not work  What can be probable solution ??

Comment: have you tried `==`? also `a==%`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `%d` won't convert a `%` or `$`. In other words, it won't put anything into a (not to mention you should be passing `&a`). When the conversion fails, it will be left on `stdin`, so you can still read it subsequently.

To know if the conversion was successful, check `scanf()`'s return value. It returns the number of successful cnversions.

```
if (1 != scanf("%d", &a)) {
  char c = 0;
  scanf(" %c", &c);
  if (c == '%' || c == '$') {
    /* done */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your if condition is not comparing `a` with `$`

change to this:
`if (a =='$')`

- **=** assignment operator
- **==** equality operator

**Edit**
do same to compare `%`
`if(a=='%')`

Answer (score 0):

try it as a=='$' or store value which u read in an integer and check